# sorting with given attribute in a collection

Tags: java, sorting, java-8

I am trying to implement sorting with given attribute in a collection let's say List.
Is there a better approach in which I don't need to modify the code if later point of time my Student class attributes gets changed(added more, deleted few or exiting modified) ?

as an enhancement of this code I love if you also can answer my below questions:-

- I also want to support sorting on **multiple attributes** (like "name: desc, emailId asc"
- Is is possible to make the method **generic **which can take any POJO class and do the sorting?

```
public static List<Student> sort(List<Student> list, Pageable pageable) {

    boolean isReverse = false;
    String sortString = pageable.getSort().toString();
    String sortBy = sortString.substring(0, sortString.indexOf(":"));
    String direction = sortString.substring(sortString.indexOf(":") + 1);
    if (direction.trim().equalsIgnoreCase("desc")) {
      isReverse = true;
    }

    switch (sortBy) {
      case "bidderId" -> list.sort(Comparator.comparing(Student::getName, Comparator.nullsLast(Comparator.naturalOrder())));
      case "bidderPipeName" ->
          list.sort(Comparator.comparing(Student::getEmailId, Comparator.nullsLast(Comparator.naturalOrder())));
    }

    if (isReverse) {
      Collections.reverse(list);
    }

    return list;
  }
```

I tried the code I mentioned in the description.
CURRENTLY MY CODE IS WORKING BUT WANT A BETTER APPROACH.

Comment: If your objects are bean-standards-complant, there are almost certainly things in Commons Collections you can implement a generic sort with

Comment: Seems to me you want to build a dynamic comparator by passing object fields to the comparator builder.

Comment: What’s your end goal? Are you just looking for a way to do sorting, or you are implementing an algorithm or library, or schoolwork?

Comment: What is a "better approach"?

Answer (score 0, accepted):

Finally I succeeded to create the method I was looking for after some effort.

```
public static <T> List<T> genSort(List<T> list, Pageable pageable) {
    // creating map of multiple sort attribute with direction
    Map<String, String> map = pageable.getSort().stream().collect(
        Collectors.toMap(p -> p.getProperty(), p -> String.valueOf(p.getDirection())));

    List<T> result = new ArrayList<>(list);
    // sorting the collection with sort attributes one by one
    for (Map.Entry<String, String> entry : map.entrySet()) {
      Comparator comparator = entry.getValue().equalsIgnoreCase("desc") ? Comparator.reverseOrder() : Comparator.naturalOrder();

      Collections.sort(result, new BeanComparator<T>(entry.getKey(), Comparator.nullsLast(comparator)));
    }
    return result;
  }
```

**Please note that my pageable contains the sort attributes like "name,desc,emailId,desc".**

I don't need separate comparator class to sort different Entities like Student, Employee etc, this method can be used to sort all of such.

Answer (score 0):

```
    public static <T> List<T> genSort(List<T> list, String fieldName) {
        List<T> result = new ArrayList<>(list);
        Collections.sort(result, new BeanComparator<T>(fieldName));
        return result;
    }
```

(Using Commons Beanutils)

Comment: thanks for your quick response, but the provided solution is not working for me. Not sure why I am getting below error.
'java.lang.NullPointerException: Cannot invoke "java.lang.Comparable.compareTo(Object)" because "obj1" is null
 at org.apache.commons.collections.comparators.ComparableComparator.compare(ComparableComparator.java:92) ~[commons-collections-3.2.2.jar:3.2.2]'

Comment: looks like I am getting the error as some of the field values are null, is there any ways to handle null values?

Comment: You should be able to use [this](https://commons.apache.org/proper/commons-beanutils/apidocs/org/apache/commons/beanutils/BeanComparator.html#BeanComparator-java.lang.String-java.util.Comparator-) ctor. And you might use [this](https://docs.oracle.com/en/java/javase/17/docs/api/java.base/java/util/Comparator.html#nullsFirst(java.util.Comparator)) or [this](https://docs.oracle.com/en/java/javase/17/docs/api/java.base/java/util/Comparator.html#nullsLast(java.util.Comparator)) with it